# @DestinationVariable No converter found

Tags: websocket, spring-boot

In my application I use webSocket and I need to transfer an object from client to server. The server method looks like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/{usersSelected}")
public void disperseMessage(@DestinationVariable("usersSelected") List<UserSelected> usersSelected) {...
```

The client- objects look like this:

```
vm.usersSelected = [];

var userSelected = {};
userSelected.userId = userId;
userSelected.institutionId = institutionId;
vm.usersSelected.push(userSelected);
```

I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.DestinationVariable java.util.List

Does anyone know how I can solve this (I use Spring Boot) - is there an annotation to prevent the exception?
Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**

Server method

```
vm.stompClient.send("/app/chat/" + vm.institutionIdOfSender + "/" + vm.userIdOfSender + "/" + vm.usersSelected + "/" + confirmation, {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': vm.name, 'id': vm.userIdOfSender, 'message': message }));
```

Client -> Server method invocation:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/{institutionIdOfSender}/{userIdOfSender}/{usersSelected}/{confirmation}")
public void disperseMessage(@DestinationVariable("institutionIdOfSender") String institutionIdOfSender,
        @DestinationVariable("userIdOfSender") String userIdOfSender, @DestinationVariable("usersSelected") String usersSelected,
        @DestinationVariable("confirmation") Boolean confirmation, final ChatMessage message) throws Exception {
```

**[EDIT2]**
I have solved it like this way, but it is not such a nice solution:

Server

```
    @MessageMapping("/chat/{institutionIdOfSender}/{userIdOfSender}/{usersSelected}/{confirmation}/{chatMessageFilter}")
public void disperseMessage(@DestinationVariable("institutionIdOfSender") String institutionIdOfSender,
        @DestinationVariable("userIdOfSender") String userIdOfSender, @DestinationVariable("usersSelected") String usersSelectedString,
        @DestinationVariable("confirmation") Boolean confirmation,
        @DestinationVariable("chatMessageFilter") ChatMessageFilterEnum chatMessageFilter, final ChatMessage message) throws Exception {

    // transfer JSON- string into List- Objects:
    final List<UserSelected> usersSelected = new ObjectMapper().readValue(usersSelectedString,
        new TypeReference<List<UserSelected>>() {});
```

at client:

```
vm.stompClient.send("/app/chat/" + vm.institutionIdOfSender + "/" + vm.userIdOfSender + "/" + JSON.stringify(vm.usersSelected) + "/" + confirmation + "/SELECTED_USERS", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': vm.name, 'id': vm.userIdOfSender, 'message': message }));
```

Do I have a chance not to convert the JSON String at server by my own? (This should be made behinde th scene)
Thanks for help!

Comment: I see you edited the code but you do not mention if the ConverterNotFoundException still happens or if the messaging is different.

Answer (score 0):

@DestinationVariable does not refer to the body of the message rather it is a placeholder for a String in the path.

e.g.(Using the same pattern as your code)

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/{chatChannel}")
public void disperseMessage(@DestinationVariable("chatChannel") String chatChannel) {...
```

If I were to send a message to /chat/allChat the value of chatChannel would be the String "allChat"

So what the error means is that it cannot convert the letters "allChat" in to a List as "allChat" would not be enough information(Unless you created a converter that grabbed a list of users from a channel which is probably not what you are going for and probably makes more sense as a service)

> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

spring.io has a great Spring Boot tutorial on WebSockets that shows an example service taking a message body that should just use the available json parser. So I just adjusted code in that tutorial to fit for you.

Javascript

```
var message = {
    'chatMessage': { 'name': vm.name, 'id': vm.userIdOfSender, 'message': message },
    'usersSelected': vm.usersSelected
}
vm.stompClient.send("/app/chat/" + vm.institutionIdOfSender + "/" + vm.userIdOfSender + "/" + confirmation + "/SELECTED_USERS", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
```

Java - Feel free to name the class ChatMessageAndUsersSelected something better

```
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/chat/{institutionIdOfSender}/{userIdOfSender}/{usersSelected}/{confirmation}/{chatMessageFilter}")
    public void disperseMessage(@DestinationVariable("institutionIdOfSender") String institutionIdOfSender,
        @DestinationVariable("userIdOfSender") String userIdOfSender,
        @DestinationVariable("confirmation") Boolean confirmation, final ChatMessageAndUsersSelected message) throws Exception {
        //Do stuff here.
    }

}
```

> https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually I could not get what I should do in order to solve the problem. Could you please explain it once again - I have edit my question at top with original code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are only allowed to send one json object I think what you need is an object where you can send both the chat message which you are successfully sending now and the userSelected possibly using different fields in a common object for example you have one parent object and it has a field for ChatMessage and it also has a field for List<UserSelected> I'll edit my answer to show this a bit.